# How to nest 2 simple CVX problems? Is it possible at all?

Tags: optimization, matlab, convex-optimization, constrained-optimization, cvx

I have the **underdetermined** outer optimization problem
$$\text{min}_{x\geq 0}\quad \|Ax-b_1\|_2^2+\|AT(x)-b_2\|_2^2$$
with $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $m<<n=64^2$ or in corresponding CVX Matlab code

```
variable x(n) nonnegative
minimize(sum( (A*x-b1).^2 + (A*T(x,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5)-b2).^2 ))
```

where `p1,...,p5` are fixed parameters required by the function `T`. Inside `T` there is another linear minimization problem
$$\begin{aligned}\text{min}_{c,q} \quad &1^\top q&\\\text{s.t.}\quad&Dc-x \leq q\\-&Dc-x \leq -q\end{aligned}$$
with $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ or in Matlab syntax

```
function value = T(x,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5)
... something happens ...
cvx_begin
    variable c(n)
    variable q(n)
    minimize sum(q)
    subject to
        D*c-x <= q
        -D*c-x >= -q
cvx_end
... something else happens and calculates return value ...
```

Unfortunately I get the error

```
Undefined function 'newcnstr' for input arguments of type 'cvx'.

Error in cvx/lt (line 22)
b = newcnstr( evalin( 'caller', 'cvx_problem', '[]' ), x, y, '<' );
```

after the `cvx_end` line in the function `T`.

I encountered this error several times before when dealing with other problems, but this time I cannot replace the outer optimization with a build in Matlab function, since `fmincon` is far to slow. Replacing the inner problem by `linprog` is too slow as well, unfortunately.

**Is it possible to nest CVX optimization problems like that? If yes, how?**
Are there any other ideas what I could try?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to nest CVX optimization problems like that? If yes, how?

I don't think you can, no. CVX is designed to model convex programs; as such, it cannot model nonconvex programs (but could model their convex relaxations). In general, the bilevel linear programming case can yield a nonconvex feasible set (see [this presentation by Chris Fricke](http://www.or.ms.unimelb.edu.au/handouts/Bilevel.pdf), slides 40-44), which would make it impossible for CVX to solve these correctly, so this construction is probably not allowable for CVX.

> Are there any other ideas what I could try?

In order to try other ideas, it would help to know if $T$ is a smooth function.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my comment is way too late but I just joined this community.

You may consider Bender's decomposition or Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition .. I've done similar thing : 
min {c'x + E [Q(x)]| x>=0}; where Q(x)= min {q'y|Wy =T(x)-d, y>=0}

I was able to solve it efficiently using Bender's decomposition.

Good Luck,